# How to write a script for delete all the logs everytime macos shutdown?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, systemevent, systemexit

I knew how to delete all the log files with terminal command "sudo rm -r /var/log" but how to set it up for system events, therefore, clear up everytime system shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can execute commands or script at startup or shutdown,

see the links below for details,

[unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/execute-a-command-before-shutdown) or [ccm](http://ccm.net/faq/3348-execute-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown-on-ubuntu) or [opensource.com](https://opensource.com/life/16/11/running-commands-shutdown-linux)